# Alternative install for python libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project in my school which requires me to install a couple python libraries. We have been blocked from using the CMD on the school computers which has proved problematic as this is the only way I know of which allows me to easily install any libraries. I also cannot see the location of the python install, I believe they are on some server which we do not have access too (although I am not confident in the matter). I believe each student is allocated  space on the server so I can install some things from the internet (however quite a few things are blocked). Most of my class has overcome this by using their own laptops however this isn't an option for me. If needs be I can try install anything at home to bring into school on a memory stick. The school computers use windows 10 and python 3.6. If there's any more information you may need please say. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install PyCharm then it has its terminal/cmd through you can install your python library. But important thing is that you must have permission to do it as you said you are on common server of the school.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.